# Mysql Large SQL query, snipped at 2,000 characters

Tags: mysql, heidisql

With the HeidiSQL db client, I am getting a `large SQL query (4.0 KB), snipped at 2,000 characters` error.  Anyone know why this is the case and what i would need to change on the below table

Please let me know which sections of the code would need updating

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `warrington_central`.`business`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `warrington_central`.`business` (
  `id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `user_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `alias_title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `primary_category` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `secondary_category` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `tertiary_category` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `premisis_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `address_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `geolocation_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `logo_path` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `telephone_number` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL ,
  `mobile` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL ,
  `fax_no` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL ,
  `website` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL ,
  `opening_times` VARCHAR(5000) NOT NULL ,
  `history_experience` VARCHAR(5000) NOT NULL ,
  `description` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  `no_of_employees` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `date_establised` DATE NULL ,
  `show_google_map` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL ,
  `show_street_view` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL ,
  `show_comment` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL ,
  `add_contact_form` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL ,
  `viewable_to_members_only` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL ,
  `link_to_user_profile` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL ,
  `admin_package_id` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `package_start_date` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  `package_end_date` DATETIME NULL ,
  `package_comment` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL ,
  `created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  `updated_by` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `updated_on` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  `approved` ENUM('Inprocess','Yes','No') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Inprocess' ,
  `visible` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `hits` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `advertise_to` DATETIME NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `alias_title` (`alias_title` ASC/* large SQL query (4.0 KB), snipped at 2,000 characters */
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

Comment: what client are you using to run this query?

Comment: 'Getting'? Does this come via HTTP? Sent by PHP? Lots of different options out there...

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can also just go to Tools > Preferences > Logging, and set the "lines in SQL log" setting to another value.

But as @doublesharp said, that's just a cosmetic thing. The query sent to the server is certainly not cut.

Comment: Much better than modifying the registry. Also, you can set the setting to 0 for no snipping.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a function of HeidiSQL and does not actually affect your query running. If it were generating errors or warnings, you would see them after the comment about your query being snipped at 2,000 characters.

See the source code here: http://code.google.com/p/heidisql/source/browse/trunk/source/main.pas?r=4127

```
prefLogSqlWidth := GetRegValue(REGNAME_LOGSQLWIDTH, DEFAULT_LOGSQLWIDTH);
```

Then the message is generate with this code

```
// Shorten very long messages
Len := Length(Msg);
snip := (prefLogSqlWidth > 0) and (Len > prefLogSqlWidth);
IsSQL := Category in [lcSQL, lcUserFiredSQL];     if snip then begin
  Msg :=
    Copy(Msg, 0, prefLogSqlWidth) +
    '/* large SQL query ('+FormatByteNumber(Len)+'), snipped at ' +
      FormatNumber(prefLogSqlWidth) +
      ' characters */';
  end else if (not snip) and IsSQL then
    Msg := Msg + Delimiter;
  if not IsSQL then
    Msg := '/* ' + Msg + ' */';
```

Seems like you can change this value in the registry (http://code.google.com/p/heidisql/source/browse/trunk/source/const.inc?r=4133)

```
REGNAME_LOGSQLWIDTH = 'logsqlwidth';
DEFAULT_LOGSQLWIDTH = 2000;
```

The key is *probably* located here `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\HeidiSQL\Servers`